Full stack pycharm project with Fastapi and react
I am working on a web app. Naturally this webapp has a frontend and a backend. The frontend would be written in react and the backend in fastapi with postgresql. I have pycharm professional and I've been trying for an hour to explain it that it is one project folder with a frontend and a backend but I can't seem to make it understand this. I always have to choose: or it's a fastapi project or it's a react project but it seems like it can't be both.
I've read some older intelliJ forum posts and it seems like in the past this was possible through modules.
However I don't know if this is still supported because in the documentation it says you should go to new|add module. However I have two problems with this:

I cannot create a new project without defining whether I want react or fastApi (I can't create an "undefined" parent project folder")
Even if I choose for example fastApi for a new project and then in that project I try to add a new module then it doesn't let me. "module" is simply not an option. 

My ideal project configuration would be the one below:
/myproject/
│
├── frontend/                  # React frontend
│   ├── public/                # Static assets like HTML files, icons
│   ├── src/                   # React source files
│   │   ├── components/        # React components
│   │   ├── App.js             # Main React application file
│   │   └── index.js           # Entry point for React application
│   ├── tests/                 # Frontend tests
│   │   ├── componentTests/    # Tests for individual components
│   │   └── integrationTests/  # Tests for component integrations
│   ├── package.json           # npm package configuration
│   └── .env                   # Environment variables for frontend
│
├── backend/                   # FastAPI backend
│   ├── .venv/                 # Python virtual environment folder
│   ├── app/                   # Python application files
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py            # Entry point for FastAPI application
│   │   ├── dependencies/      # Dependency files for API (e.g., database session)
│   │   ├── models/            # Database models
│   │   ├── schemas/           # Pydantic schemas for data validation
│   │   └── routes/            # API routes
│   ├── tests/                 # Backend tests
│   ├── Pipfile                # Pipenv environment and dependency file
│   └── Pipfile.lock           # Lock file for exact pipenv dependencies
│
├── e2e-tests/                 # End-to-end tests that involve both frontend and backend
│
├── nginx/                     # Nginx configuration files for routing and proxying
│   └── nginx.conf
│
├── docker-compose.yml         # Docker Compose file to orchestrate containers (React, FastAPI, PostgreSQL)
│
├── .git/                      # Git repository metadata folder
├── .gitignore                 # Specifies untracked files to ignore (e.g., .env, node_modules)
└── README.md                  # Project documentation and setup instructions

Is it true that this is not possible? And if this is not possible how do you handle a full stack application with pycharm?

why not going in with Intellij ? I dont think PyCharm is supposed to handle react applications

Do you mean Intellij IDEA? But that's for Java? Pycharm professional supports react because you can create a "React" project. You just can't do react and pycharm in one project

It's Java-Oriented but you can use it with other languages - not sure for the community edition

I asked their official support now because pycharm professional really supports both types of projects, I just need to figure out how to combine them into one :/ Seems a bit odd to me to go to an IDE that is focused on Java when it should work.
